# Terms query not returning results for list of strings

Tags: elasticsearch

I have this Elastic query which fails to return the desired results for `terms.letter_score`. I'm certain there is available matches in the index. This query (excluding letter_score) returns the expected filtered results but nothing with `letter_score`. The only difference is (as far as I can tell), is that the `cat_id` values is a list of integers vs strings. Any ideas of what could be the issue here? I'm basically trying to get it to match ANY value from the `letter_score` list.

Thanks

```
{
   "size": 10,
   "query": {
      "bool": {
         "filter": [
            {
               "terms": {
                  "cat_id": [
                     1, 
                     2,
                     4
                  ]
               }
            },
            {
               "terms": {
                  "letter_score": [
                     "A",
                     "B",
                     "E"
                  ]
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like your `letter_score` field is of type `text`, and hence, has been analyzed, so the tokens `A`, `B` and `E` have been stored as `a`, `b` and `e` so the `terms` query won't match them.

Also if that's the case, the probability is high that the token `a` has been ignored at indexing time because it is a stop word and the `standard` analyzer (default) ignores them (if you're using ES 5+).

A first approach is to use a `match` query instead of `terms`, like this:

```
{
   "match": {
      "letter_score": "A B E"
   }
}
```

If that still doesn't work, I suggest that you change the mapping of your `letter_score` field to `keyword` (requires reindexing your data) and then your query will work as it is now